# How to read Inverse Pole Figures (IPF) images

Tags: diffraction, data-analysis, imaging

When ([Electron BackScatter Diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_backscatter_diffraction)) EBSD maps are procesed the output crystallographic orientation is derived into Euler map and three [Inverse pole figures](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47492/how-to-create-an-inverse-pole-figure-color-map) (IPF) maps.

In the example there is IPF-Y image of ferrite/cementite structure, large areas are ferritic, the "random pixels" are affiliated with cementite.

[image: Coordinates]
[image: Map]

My question is, what information I can read from such images?

- There are three IPF-x maps, all with colourmap and [Miller indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index). Miller indices describe position of a plane in respect to crystallographic axes.*
- Can be red-coloured grain assigned to Miller indices of (001) and the Blue ones to (111) directly?
- If the colour is somewhere in the map, say it has coordinates $[r,g,b]=[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]$ can we assume that the miller indices would be:
  $$r\cdot(001)+g\cdot(101)+b\cdot(111)=(0,0,1)+(3,0,3)+(6,6,6)=(9,6,10)$$

---

(*) In [X-Ray Diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography) (XRD) the plane conidered is the sample surface or plane parallel to the sample holder. In symmetric crystals, like cubic, the planes (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) are considered equal and labeled as (1,0,0) only.

Comment: ***Please*** define abbreviations and acronyms upon first use!

Comment: @garyp I've editted the question with respect to your comment.